# Why 404 Page Not Found error occurs except default controller

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, http-status-code-404

I am using OS Ubuntu.
I am creating the application on codeigniter and facing problem while I am running my code. Only default controller is working, other then that are not working and application through the error:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Code: Controller Name: Test

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hi this is Test Controller";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when index.php is included in URL (i.e. `http://servername/index.php/test`)?

Comment: Would you add your routes file aswell and the config file where it says `$config['uri_protocol']`

Answer (score 1):

There may be many reason where CI can display `404 Page Not Found`.

As example

1. If the File does not exists in your controller folder.
2. If you using CI-3 in that case File name and class name should be same and UCfirst.So your controller file name should be `Test.php` not `test.php`.
3. If your url is not valid. like you using link without index.php but you did not do steps to work without it(.htaccess,..).

**Note**:
Try to use your link `http://your_site_base_url/index.php/test` if it does not work means you have any of those problem.